# At sign (@) in Perl Regular Expression

Tags: regex, perl

What is the meaning of `@` and `@@` in this Perl Regex (<strike>which removes comment from C code</strike>):

```
$line =~ s@//.*@@;
```

What is the difference from `$line =~ s///.*//;`?

Couldn't find any reference to `@` in the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Note that that approach is broken in the general case. E.g. `printf("a // b\n");` will be mangled into `printf("a ` by that regex replacement.

Comment: Thanks, the script sanitize all strings beforehand to avoid these kind of things.

Comment: That approach is also broken in the general case. E.g. `printf(/* "foo */ "a // b"); // "`.

Comment: @melpomene The only thing that may work is the preprocessor/compiler itself; with GNU cpp/gcc: `cpp -fpreprocessed -P infile`

Comment: @mosvy No, it's quite easy to do this correctly with a single `s///` (and support even continuation lines and trigraphs), but you can't do it in stages or work linewise.

Comment: @melpomene "but you can't do it in stages" which means that it doesn't scale and isn't worth wasting time with.

Comment: @mosvy You've lost me. Are you saying tokenizing C is pointless and no one should do it?

Comment: @melpomene explain how you you're going to process `/*..*/` comments with a single s///, *without* loading the whole file in the memory. `cpp` is able to do that almost as fast as `cat`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195445/discussion-between-melpomene-and-mosvy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the meaning of `@` and `@@` in this Perl Regex

It doesn't have any meaning. The `s` (substitute) operator can use any delimiter, with a special case for paired delimiters (`{}`, `<>`, `[]`, `()`). The same could be written as `s,//.*,,`, `s#//.*##` or `s{//.*}{}`.

If the `/` weren't replaced with `@` or other delimiter, it would've had to be escaped in the regexp and replacement, which would've given something ugly like `s/\/\/.*//`.

This is all documented under ["Quote and Quote-like Operators"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in the `perlop(1)` manpage -- including the special treatment of the single quote (`'`) delimiter, which prevents variable interpolation.

> What is the difference from `$line =~ s///.*//;`?

The difference is that that example is broken and doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps we could comment that the original code chose @ as a delimiter as opposed to some other character, on the grounds that they did not want to escape some other character in the regex.

Comment: `$line =~ s///.*//` would be parsed as `($line =~ s///) . <Syntax error: Expression expected>`

Answer (score 2):

The `@` does not appear in the regex. It is being used as the delimiter in the substitution operator.

The substitution operator is usually written as `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`. The `PATTERN` is the regex and the `REPLACEMENT` is treated as a double-quoted string. In the standard version of the operator, the slash character (`/`) is used as the delimiter, but Perl allows the programmer to choose pretty much any character as the delimiter. This is usually done to avoid having to escape characters that appear in either the pattern or the replacement.

In your example code, the programmer has chosen to use the `@` character as the delimiter. This is a slightly unusual choice :-)

As the pattern includes `/` characters, then they would need to be escaped if the standard delimiter was used:

```
$line =~ s/\/\/.*//;
```

This looks ugly and using a different delimiter is a good choice. I would have gone with a less confusing character, like `|`.

```
$line =~ s|//.*||;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a different symbol that you don't have to escape the `/` in the regex itself. Could be pretty much any other special symbol, too:

```
$line =~ s#//.*##g;
$line =~ s!//.*!!g;
$line =~ s&//.*&&g;
$line =~ s|//.*||g;
```